# Java JMenu doesent work properly

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I have been working on an html text editing program for a while and i wondered if anyone could help me with this small problem. I have two jmenus but one of them are misbehaving. i have two problems. 1 the menu item in the menu has a submenu arrow although it is not a sub menu [image: The problem]

2. is that i have added an action listener to the menu but when i click the action doesent happen. here is the code.

   ```
   import java.awt.GridLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.FileWriter;
   import java.io.IOException;

   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JMenu;
   import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
   import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
   import javax.swing.JTextArea;


   public class Window {

   static boolean saved = false;
   static boolean opened = false;
   static File saveDirectory = null;
   static File openDirectory = null;

   static final JTextArea editor = new JTextArea(10,50);

   public static void openWindowEditor(){
   JFrame f = new JFrame("Easy HTML Text editor");

   JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

   JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

   JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu("View");

   JMenuItem fileMenuSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
   JMenuItem fileMenuOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
   JMenuItem fileMenuSaveAs = new JMenuItem("Save as...");

   JMenuItem viewMenuEasyInsert = new JMenu("Easy insert");

   fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);

   viewMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);

   menuBar.add(fileMenu);
   menuBar.add(viewMenu);

   fileMenu.add(fileMenuSave);
   fileMenu.add(fileMenuOpen);
   fileMenu.add(fileMenuSaveAs);

   viewMenu.add(viewMenuEasyInsert);

   fileMenuSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           save(editor.getText());
       }
   });

   fileMenuOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           open();
       }
   });

   fileMenuSaveAs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           saveAs();
       }
   });

   viewMenuEasyInsert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           openEasyInsertWindow();
       }
   });

   f.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
   f.add(editor);

   f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
   f.pack();
   f.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void open(){
   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
   int returnVal = chooser.showDialog(null, "open");

   if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
   File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

   try{
   editor.read(new FileReader(file), null);
   }catch(IOException e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       }
   }
   }

   public static void save(String text){
   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
   File file = null;

   int returnVal = chooser.showDialog(null, "Save");
   if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
   file = (chooser.getSelectedFile());

   String result = text.replace("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));

   saveDirectory = chooser.getSelectedFile();
   try{
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
   fw.write(result);
   fw.close();
   saved = true;
   }catch(IOException e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       }
   }
   }

   public static void saveAs(){
   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
   File dir;

   int returnVal = chooser.showDialog(null, "Save as...");
   if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
   dir = chooser.getSelectedFile();
   try{
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(dir);
       fw.write(editor.getText());
       fw.close();
   }catch(IOException e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       }
   }
   }

   public static void openEasyInsertWindow(){
   JFrame f = new JFrame("easy insert");

   JButton insertDivButton = new JButton("Insert <div> element");
   JButton openInsertSettings = new JButton("Open the insert settings");

   f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
   f.add(insertDivButton);
   f.add(openInsertSettings);

   f.pack();
   f.setVisible(true);

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(editor, "Easy insert");
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you've defined it as a `JMenu` and not a `JMenuItem`

```
JMenuItem viewMenuEasyInsert = new JMenu("Easy insert");
```

should be

```
JMenuItem viewMenuEasyInsert = new JMenuItem("Easy insert");
```